# How to list products NOT bought by a customer?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 3 tables - `customer`, `product` and `customerproduct` (linked table containing customers and the products they bought).
i want to list each customer with the products **not** bought by him.

**Example**

**Customers**

```
Tom
Jim
Harry
```

**Product**

```
Shampoo
Brush
Shoe
Box
```

**Customerproduct**

```
Jim   | box
Jim   | brush
Tom   | brush
Harry | shampoo
```

So, my query should display:

```
Jim | shampoo
Jim | shoe
Tom | shampoo
Tom | shoe
Tom | box
...
```

I need to use lookup to get my customers and products. Making a separate table CustomersandProducts table and feeding it in manually is not an option.
Surely, there must be a way to get the results using NOT EXISTS, NOT IN, etc?

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  Is this a homework problem?

Comment: I have. I am not getting the desired result. It can be solved if i don't use lookups and use the query wiz to find unmatched records. But that doesn't help my problem.

Comment: Show us the query please.

Comment: This just gives me a blank. I know lookups make it complicated. Perhaps it has to be designed in VB. In that case, what do I do? Is it possible to get the result using just SQL?

Comment: SELECT  Table1.Customer, Table2.Product, Table3.ID
FROM Table1,Table2,Table3; This is query1

Comment: Not able to generate the query properly. It should only list each customer against each product. Then I intend to run it against table3 (containing customers and products they bought) in the unmatched query wiz

Comment: Had deleted the relationships. Recreated them. Sorry about that. Here's the updated query: SELECT Table1.Customer, Table2.Product, Table3.ID
FROM Table2 INNER JOIN (Table1 INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table1.ID = Table3.Customer) ON Table2.ID = Table3.Product;

Comment: This query won't even run.

Comment: SELECT Table1.Customer, Table2.Product, Table3.ID
FROM Table2 INNER JOIN (Table1 INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table1.ID = Table3.Customer) ON Table2.ID = Table3.Product;

Comment: This is just replicating table3 :(

Comment: Query2:SELECT Table1.ID, Table2.ID
FROM Table1, Table2;

Comment: With query2, if i now use the unmatched records wiz i get the following sql:  SELECT Table3.Customer, Table3.Product
FROM Table3 LEFT JOIN Query2 ON Table3.[Customer] = Query2.[Table1].[ID]
WHERE (((Query2.Table1.ID) Is Null));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to product join customer and product to get all permutation and combination of customer and product. then just lookup in actual customer product table.

Try following query:

```
select c.cname,p.pname
customers c,
product p
where c.name,p.name not in (
select cp_i.cname,cp_i.pname
from customerproduct cp_i)
```

This query will be extremely resource sensitive(cpu/io etc.) if number of rows are high in any of table.

another approach:

```
select c.cname,p.pname
customers c,
product p
where not exists (
select 1
from customerproduct cp_i
where cp_i.cname=c.cname
and cp_i.pname=p.pname)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Will have to modify this to try on my own DB but at least it gives me a start!

Comment: I entered the following in my access query but getting syntax error: SELECT Table1.Customer, Table2.Product
FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE Table1.Customer, Table2.Product NOT IN
(SELECT Table3.Customer, Table3.Product 
FROM Table3);

Comment: add bracket before Table1.Customer, Table2.Product NOT IN..it should be (Table1.Customer, Table2.Product) NOT IN...also let me know exact error description.

Comment: I added the brackets. Getting this: "You have written a subquery that can return more than one field without using EXISTS reserved word in the main query's FROM clause. Revise the SELECT statement of the subquery to request only one field.

Comment: @SougataNandyadded another approach using not exists as well. you may need to change query a bit. but it will give you idea.